# shared object compilation error

Tags: compilation, shared-libraries, shared

I am trying to compile a library libEncryption.so.

Here is what my make file conatins:

```
cc -g -w -fPIC  -c -ISource/Header -I//usr/local/ssl/include -L//usr/local/ssl/lib -     lssl -lcrypto Source/Common/C/Encryption.c -DBIT64 -DDBG -DLITTLEENDIAN -DOMS -DRMS
mv Encryption.o Objects/Encryption.o
ld -fPIC -G  Objects/Encryption.o  -L/usr/local/ssl/lib -lssl -lcrypto -o   libEncryption.so
```

On running this i keep on getting following error

> ld: /usr/local/ssl/lib/libcrypto.a(sha1dgst.o): relocation R_X86_64_32 against `a local symbol' can not be used when making a shared object; recompile with -fPIC
>   /usr/local/ssl/lib/libcrypto.a: could not read symbols: Bad value

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's telling you libcrypto.a was not compiled with `fPIC`.

You should either rebuild it with `-fPIC`, or drop the use of `-fPIC` when compiling your stuff.